# Как сделать локальный прокси?

Tags: windows, proxy, vpn

Есть 5 vpn подключений(5 vpn серверов) по логину паролю. Можно подключиться через pptp. Подскажите программу, в которую можно внести данные для подключения к этим vpn, она подключится и сделает из них локальные прокси вида: 127.0.0.1:1111...

Comment: Насколько мне известно, такой программы нет.

Comment: ну а на линуксе так сделать можно? С помощью программы 3proxy или чем то подобным?

Comment: если я правильно понял задачу то должно получиться, например, squid-ом